# Hide a worksheet based on username

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I already have a macro below that un-hides a worksheet at the click of a button and works okay. However I want this macro to be changed so that ONLY two users (whose usernames are "JSMITH" AND "DTAYLOR") are able to unhide this sheet called "Rates".

If someone else (whose username is not one of the two mentioned above) tries to unhide the sheet, I want Excel to display a message "you're not authorised to open this".

Moreover, I need to make sure that only those two users are able to un-hide in a traditional way without vba (eg by right-clicking on a visible worksheet tab and choose Unhide or from any worksheet tab, choose Format, Sheet, and then Unhide).

Can you please advise how to modify the following code to do the all the things described above?

```
Sub Hide_AllRatesSheet()

Worksheets("Rates").Visible = False 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names").Activate 

End Sub
```

Comment: Hiding the sheet is not exactly secure. Protect the sheet and put a password on it?

Comment: thanks but no, I need to hide it. Can you advise how to change the code above please? thanks

Comment: Note that posts requesting (a) [urgency](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) and (b) free work are in danger of being downvoted. In general, readers would prefer that you do not regard your questions as more important that the hundreds of others that came in today, and that you are willing to expend your own efforts to come to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: you could use `xlSheetVeryHidden` property to allow unhiding it only from code (and not by mouse right-click).

Try something like the code below:

```
Sub Hide_AllRatesSheet()

Select Case Environ$("username") '<-- check username
    Case "JSMITH", "DTAYLOR"  
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Rates" Then '<-- make sure "Rates" is not the ActiveSheet
            Worksheets("Rates").Visible = False
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names").Activate
            Worksheets("Rates").Visible = False
        End If
    Case Else
        MsgBox "you're not authorised to open this"
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: apologies, it was daft of me but I gave you the wrong code above. The correct code which I need to modify as described above is as follows. Any chance you could please help? cant figure out based on your suggestions above.                                                                                     Sub GoToRates_WS()
    Worksheets("Rates").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rates").Activate
End Sub

Comment: I came up with this but it doesn't work:                                                      Sub GoToRates_WS()                                                                      Select Case Environ$("username")                                          Case "jsmith", "taylor"                                                                 Worksheets("Rates").Visible = True                                              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rates").Activate                                              Case Else  MsgBox "you're not authorised to open this" End Select End Sub

Comment: @Elena  what are u trying to achieve ? What is the purpose of your code ?